# Xamarin Android : How to turn on infrared lights on Doogee S99 Phone

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I tried really hard but I am unable to turn on Infrared Lights which is available for Infrared Camera available on device Doogee S99 model.
This device uses Night vision camera so that you can see clearly in the very dark, during night vision camera is on it also turns on Infrared Lights which is not visible to our eyes but if you look in dark this camera gives clear vision.
I am developing an app for my client and I can use night vision camera but unable to turn on Infrared lights.
Any help is really appreciated.

To turn on Infrared Lights which is turning on using native camera app only.

Comment: What does the device documentation say?